# Rename file using FSO MoveFile and Name-As not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to rename a file from `"X"` to `"XY"` in the same folder. I have tried using File System Object and just the Name X as Y function, but neither is working.  I do have the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference installed.  The code completes successfully but the file name does not change,  Please advise.

```
    Dim FSO As Object
Dim srcPath As String
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim fldrName As String

srcPath = "C:\"

i = 1
Set FileSysObj_1 = New FileSystemObject

For Each Folder_Obj1 In FileSysObj_1.GetFolder(srcPath).SubFolders
i = i + 1
On Error Resume Next

        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

            'If the file exists in the folder then rename it
            If Dir(srcPath & Folder_Obj1.Name & "_Hotel.xlsx") Then

                fldrName = Folder_Obj1.Name
                FromPath = srcPath & fldrName & "_Hotel.xlsx"
                ToPath = srcPath & "Hotel.xlsx"

                '***  Neither of the following two lines work to rename the file
                FSO.MoveFile FromPath, ToPath
                Name FromPath As ToPath

            Else
                    MsgBox "File doesn't exist."

            End If

Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question mentions that you're trying to rename a file in the same folder but, according to your code, you're actually moving it to the root of `C:`. You can use the following code as a replacement for what you have above. It will rename the file in its original folder.

```
Dim objFSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder

For Each objFolder In objFSO.GetFolder("c:\").SubFolders
    If objFSO.FileExists(objFolder.Path & "\_Hotel.xlsx") Then

        ' Rename...
        objFSO.GetFile(objFolder.Path & "\_Hotel.xlsx").Name = "Hotel.xlsx"

    End If
Next
```

Comment: Happy to help. Please [upvote/accept any answers you find helpful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1):

Go to the tools menu in your VBA IDE and select references. Select "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".

Then declare

```
Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
```

Then the MoveFile should work.

Comment: The object needs an instance. As-is, that would give the OP run-time error 91.. But kudos for early-binding the scripting runtime ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Big Warning!

When using MoveFile for renaming a file it will only work with complete filenames without wildcards so 
 fso.MoveFile ( "somepath\myfile1.*" "somepath\myfile2" ) will error while
 fso.MoveFile ( "somepath\myfile1.pdf" "somepath\myfile2.pdf" ) will work.
Wildcard in the first argument only works when really moving to a different location without changing the filename. Then the second argument should end with "\" Wonder why the documentation on MSDN is so cryptic.