# Name command -> rename file

Tags: vba, ms-access, rename

It's my first question here, so I hope it's at the right place here.

I am working with VBA from Access 365 on a Win10 computer. I try to rename files in a certain folder. It should be possible to use the `name` command for this. I have found some examples.

But problem is that "name" is not known by my VBA. Probably I need an additional library or something like this, but I can not find what I need.

Comment: Should work with the default references. I'm not on Access 365 but I don't see that being removed. Can you post the code you have that is erroring and the actual error you are getting.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885555/rename-file-using-fso-movefile-and-name-as-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your probably miss the **As**:

```
Name "d:\folder\oldname.txt" As "d:\folder\newname.txt"
```

Comment: my code is like this:

OldName = sFile: NewName = sFile & ".png" ' Define file names.
Name OldName As NewName ' Rename file.

Comment: You may need to set the current drive and directory or to specify the full path in both names.